# Does Android Studio support Code completion for C/C++?

Tags: android-studio, autocomplete

The code completion is fine on Android Studio java project. But I want to use Android Studio to edit some existing C file(.cpp).

for example, if i have declared some function, then i type the function in other section. But the android studio doesn't show up the code suggestion or some debugging.

Can Android Studio support Code completion for C/C++ like this:?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, as long as the project is setup to use the NDK and the C/CPP sources are included in the project.

Try pulling the ndk [sample repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) and try opening one of the projects.

If you have a java project and want to edit some arbitrary C or C++ source, then no.  It does not have enough information about the source file, include paths, compiler etc...

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses Android.mk to build, it will be a bug of Android Studio. I have been reported.

- [Android.mk project cannot show code completion for cpp.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=266589)

Comment: opposite for me, code completion for android.mk build projects works, but doesn't work for cmake build projects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that old version of Android Studio does not support code completion of jni native build (with Android.mk as configuration file), and that should already be fixed now.

But if you are using CMake in your project as external building tool and code completion still does not work, It's probably because you have **more than one version** of cmake installed. You can try to remove extra ones from SDK manager and restart Android Studio, it should work.

To see installed CMake version, you can open the SDK manager and check the 'show package details' on the right bottom. You can view cmake tools installed with different versions.

[image]